# access denied error when retrieving temporary credentials from aws with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get a set of temporary credentials from AWS using `boto3` following [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html).

```py
import boto3
from botocore.errorfactory import ClientError

# create an STS client object that represents a live connection to the
# STS service
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

# Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
# ARN and a role session name
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="aws:iam::123456789:role/Upload_Data_To_S3",
    RoleSessionName="iam-s3-upload"
)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary
# credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a
# connection to Amazon S3
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)
```

I get `AccessDenied` error with the following context:

```
Exception has occurred: ClientError
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/Yury is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: aws:iam::123456789:role/Upload_Data_To_S3
  File "/home/ystanev/git-projects/ap_renewables/HighSpeed/s3-data-upload/s3_upload.py", line 18, in <module>
    RoleSessionName="iam-s3-upload"
```

My account number and the account number on the role match, thus I'm not sure why I can't assume a role under my own account. I've checked the IAM permissions under the AWS console, my account is attached to IAMFullAccess group.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*",
                "organizations:DescribeAccount",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:DescribePolicy",
                "organizations:ListChildren",
                "organizations:ListParents",
                "organizations:ListPoliciesForTarget",
                "organizations:ListRoots",
                "organizations:ListPolicies",
                "organizations:ListTargetsForPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've checked the [knowledge centre](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-error/), but I'm not sure if this applies to my case as IAM role is under my account.

How can I check is I have the permission to assume the role, and if I don't set it to allowed.

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: Does the IAM role have a trust relationship allowing your IAM user to assume the role?

Comment: Also, understand that in order to be able to assume an IAM role, you first need IAM credentials so that you can invoke sts:AssumeRole. Typically these are lower-permissioned credentials (perhaps even solely allowed to assume the named role).

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs the permission `sts:AssumeRole`. I don't see that in your policy.  And then as a comment indicates, you need to make sure the Trust Relationship of the role you're assuming  allows the account number of your user to assume it.  The Trust Policy would end up looking something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account number of the role>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Best Practice would be to only allow your user's specific principal ARN to assume the role in the Trust Relationship, and then in the policy attached to your user you would explicitly list what roles can be assumed via `sts:AssumeRole` as opposed to allowing `*` access.

Comment: how can I actually check the trust policy?

Comment: You can click on your role in the console and then click the "Trust relationships" tab and then the "Edit trust relationship" button

Comment: I've modified my role, [trust policy](https://pastebin.com/dnPGA96E) to look as your example, but I'm not sure if the argument in "AWS" in correct

Comment: yes, that looks ok.  why do you have a trust relationship with s3 in addition to that?

Comment: I don't know, it was there already, the permissions on the role is set to AmazonS3FullAccess, as I need to be able to read/write to the bucket.

Comment: Why would S3 ever need to assume a role?  I haven't come across a case like that in my career at least.  the gist is:
you have a principal (your user in this case) that needs permission to assume a role.  and then the role needs to trust that principal.  You would then attach S3 access policies to the role

Comment: I can access the S3 directly with my credentials, just fine. My code, will be running on the remote laptop. I want to avoid storing the credentials anywhere on the machine or in the git repo, but I'm not sure if that's even doable.

Comment: That's a separate idea from having a Trust Relationship with S3.  The Trust Relationship should be with your user's principal like you currently have.  And then you need to permission your user to assume the role.  And then you need to add the S3 permissions on the role.  It looks like we are being suggested to do a Chat on this rather than talk in the comments.  But, I need to step away for a while, and so hopefully you have enough to go on.  regardless you should never store aws creds in github.  your current role idea won't get you around requiring creds

Comment: ie- because the creds represent your user that is then assuming a role.  it would be a separate discussion to discuss good ways for you to avoid requiring keys